# Selecting and updating any number of rows in large table using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, random

I've got a large table, about 10 million rows, and I'm trying to build a function that selects a random number of rows (anything between 1 and all), updates a field on the selected rows to x (winner) and updates the field on remaining rows to y (loser).

All rows have a unique id but not all rows will be selected from (the table has competition entries for a number of competitions but the function needs to select winners for one competition only).

I've considered ordering by random but it's too slow for a big table.

I've also considered assigning a random value into the row when it's inserted into the table so that it can be used to order but it would have to be unique and there can be batch updates for thousands of rows so it would be slow to assign a unique random value to each row.

There's too much data to save the result as an array and shuffle.

Can anyone suggest other solutions?

This is how I would do it if the table wasn't huge:

```
function getWinnersLosers($winnercount,$allwinners) {

    // Must have draw id and ticketstatus id
    if ( ! $this->draw_id || ! $this->ticketstatus_id ) return false;

    // Update winners
    $this->db->where('draw_id', $this->draw_id);
    $this->db->where('ticketstatus_id', CONST_TICKETSTATUS_ENTERED);
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'RANDOM');
    if ( ! $allwinners ) $this->db->limit($winnercount);
    $data = array( 'ticketstatus_id' => CONST_TICKETSTATUS_WINNERUNCLAIMED );
    $query = $this->db->update('drawtickets',$data);

    // Update losers (remaining tickets)
    $this->db->where('draw_id', $this->draw_id);
    $this->db->where('ticketstatus_id !=', CONST_TICKETSTATUS_WINNERUNCLAIMED);
    $data = array( 'ticketstatus_id' => CONST_TICKETSTATUS_LOSE );
    $query = $this->db->update('drawtickets',$data);

}
```

Comment: try to use Datamapper library

Comment: How would an ORM help? It sounds like an ORM would make the problem worse.